# how to get data between two dates where day, month and year are stored in separate columns in android sqlite without altering the table structure

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table where i stored the date as day, month and year, now i am facing a problem in retriving the data between the two dates. I search the stack overflow with the similar kind of questions, many of them storing the date in single string, and one gave the solution to alter the table structure, but i dont want to change the structure of the table because the kind of structure is followed in the same application developed in windows, there its working fine. I have referred a lot of entries but no one give the solution i am looking for. 
I tried with the queries like

```
select distinct referencenumber,transday,transmonth,transyear,customernumber,status
from hhTran01
where (substr(transyear,0)||substr(transmonth,0)||substr(transday,0) >= '20131009')
and (substr(transyear,0)||substr(transmonth,0)||substr(transday,0) <= '20131014');
```

and

```
select distinct referencenumber,transday,transmonth,transyear,customernumber,status
from hhTran01
where cast(cast(transmonth as varchar)+'-'+cast(transday as varchar)+'-'+cast(transyear as varchar) as datetime) between cast(cast(10 as varchar)+'-'+cast(16 as varchar)+'-'+cast(2013 as varchar) as datetime)
and cast(cast(11 as varchar)+'-'+cast(21 as varchar)+'-'+cast(2013 as varchar) as datetime)
and companycode =07
```

please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: 10000*Y + 100* ... what it means?

Comment: `... WHERE 10000*transyear+100*transmonth+transday >= 20131009 ...`